# How to get the values from a submitted do...while form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have the following code with a form inside a list that should submit the element through Ajax. The values in the form is repeated through a do ... while loop, so that the list become a dynamically list, like in this picture:

[image: SS of the GUI]

But when I click a button, the only element that is sent through the Ajax code is the value of the last button, even though I click on Oranges for example.

The code is as follow:

```
<script>
function submitForm() {
    $.ajax({type:'POST', url: 'jQuery-ajax-demo.php', data:$('#MyJobsForm').serialize(), success: function(response) {
    $('#myJobs_Right').find('.form_result').html(response);
    }});

    return false;
}
</script>

</head>

<body>

<ul id="btn_MyJobs" data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
<li id="MyJobs_List" class="push">
  <form id="MyJobsForm"  onsubmit="return submitForm();">
    <?php do { ?>
      <input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['cargo']; ?>">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['cargo']; ?>">
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <?php } while ($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1)); ?>
  </form>
</li>
</ul>

<div id="myJobs_Right">
 <div class="form_result"> </div>
</div>

</body>
```

The `jQuery-ajax-demo.php` page looks like this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['name'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];

    ?>
    Your Name Is: <?php echo $name; ?><br />
    <?php
    die();
}
?>
```

Comment: your input needs both name and id to serialize.   name='name' id='name' or whatever.

Comment: Your form elements all have the same names; you'll need to change the code so that the `name` attribute has a different value on each iteration of the loop.

Comment: @andrewsi How do I do that, when the form elements is dynamically?

Comment: @user1825067 - the easiest way is to add a counter - concatenate the value onto the `name`, and increment it at the end of the loop. You can also use `name='name[]'`, which will pass you an array of all names on the form. Finally, you could have each name in its own form. What you should use depends entirely on what you need your form to do.

Comment: @andrewsi When using `name='name[]'` the result is instead that the output just states: "Your name is: Array" ??
I want to submit the values of the hidden fields to the `jQuery-ajax-demo.php` page that should show the values in the ´myJobs_Right`div.

Comment: @user1825067 - that's because you're passing an array of all the names, instead of just one. If you do just want one, do as the answer suggests, and put your form tags inside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to do it this way, then you might try creating a new form for each button:

```
<?php do { ?>
  <form onsubmit="return submitForm(this);"> <!--Note I added "this" -->
      <input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['cargo']; ?>">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['cargo']; ?>">
      <br/>
      <br/>
  </form>
<?php } while ($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1)); ?>
```

Then the only value that will get posted will be the hidden value that is in the form whose button you clicked. I updated the onsubmit call above to include `this` in the call. So you can do the below in your function:

```
function submitForm(form) {
    var $form = $(form);
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST', 
        url: 'jQuery-ajax-demo.php', 
        data:$form.serialize(), 
        success: function(response) {
            $('#myJobs_Right').find('.form_result').html(response);
        }
    });

    return false;
}
```

Comment: After I have putted the form tags inside the loop and added `this`
should I then replace my own function with yours above or where should I add it?

Comment: I do now see where it should go, but I'm getting an error message in the line: `function submitForm(this) {` It seems like it is the `this` inside the () that it is complaining about?